# Update table based on combination of all columns

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to update update column based on combination of all columns.

Table A

```
NUM_1 NUM_2 NUM_3 Name
----- ----- ----- ---- 
    1     4     6 Test1
    4     4     5 Test2
    4     4     3 Test3
```

Table B

```
NUM_1 NUM_2 NUM_3 Name
----- ----- ----- ---- 
    1     4     6 Final_1
    4     4     5 Final_2
    4     4     3 Final_3
```

If three columns NUM1,NUM2,NUM 3 matches then I need to update Name in Table A with value from Table B.

Is there any simple script using any correlated query or another thing?

Comment: Can you share your table structure, and explain the problem in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle doesn't support ANSI 92 joins for updates which would make this easy but we can achieve the same thing through MERGE.

```
merge into tableA a
using ( select * from tableB ) b
on ( a.num1 = b.num1
     and a.num2 = b.num2
     and a.num3 = b.num3)
when matched then
    update
    set a.name = b.name
/
```

Note: this solution assumes `(num1, num2, num3)` is a unique key on `tableB`. But any solution will require such uniqueness (otherwise how will you know which instance of `name` to apply to `tableA`?).

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
SQL> select * From a;

      NUM1       NUM2       NUM3 NAME
---------- ---------- ---------- --------------------
         1          4          6 test1      --> according to table B data, this
         4          4          5 test2      --> and this NAME should be updated
         4          4          0 test3
         1          2          3 test4

SQL> select * From b;

      NUM1       NUM2       NUM3 NAME
---------- ---------- ---------- --------------------
         1          4          6 final1
         4          4          5 final2
         4          4          3 final3

SQL> update a set
  2    a.name = (select b.name from b
  3              where b.num1 = a.num1
  4                and b.num2 = a.num2
  5                and b.num3 = a.num3
  6             )
  7  where exists (select null from b
  8                where b.num1 = a.num1
  9                  and b.num2 = a.num2
 10                  and b.num3 = a.num3
 11               );

2 rows updated.

SQL>
SQL> select * From a;

      NUM1       NUM2       NUM3 NAME
---------- ---------- ---------- --------------------
         1          4          6 final1
         4          4          5 final2
         4          4          0 test3
         1          2          3 test4

SQL>
```